# ¿Cómo acceder a un archivo json, desde el contexto de la pagina web?

Tags: extensión-google-chrome

Mi intención es consultar un archivo JSON (forma parte de los archivos de la extensión) desde el contexto de la pagina web.

En el método 1 intento acceder al documento json a través de `Fetch` usando `chrome.runtime.getURL('url')`, para obtener la URL del archivo. Pero este método no funciona.

En el metodo 2, intento acceder al documento json atreves de los mensajes usando `onMessage` y `sendMessage`. Pero el método no me funciona.

Archivos: **Método 1 y 2**

```
// manifest.json
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"],
    "js": ["./start.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": false
  }
]
```

```
// data.json
{
 "title": "Hello Word"
}
```

Archivos: **Método 1**

```
await function getData () {
 const url = chrome.runtime.getURL('data.json');
 const response = await fetch(url);
 const data = response.json();

 data...
}
```

> 

Archivos: **Método 2**

```
// start.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => console.log(message));
```

```
// background.js
await function sendData () {
 const response = await fetch('data.json');
 const data = response.json();

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data);
}
```